# Scala case classes and constructors

Tags: scala

I'm finding myself writing a lot of (sort of) boilerplate code. For example say I have the following traits

```
trait Foo {
  def x: Int
}

trait Bar {
  def y: Boolean
  def z: String
}
```

Then I want a case class that does no more or less than implement these.

```
case class MyClass(x: Int, y: Boolean, z: String) extends Foo with Bar
```

This doesn't seem annoying, but now imagine that my traits have a dozen `def`s each and that the names `x`, `y`, and `z` are much longer. Writing the case class out means I have to rewrite all of these as arguments of `MyClass`.

Is there a way to generate the `x: Int, y: Boolean, z: String` constructor part automatically based on the traits I extend?

Comment: Well, you can override def with def from your case class. In that case You would not have to generate these vals in the first place. Also does all the implementations of your trait have val implementation of its def? If that's the case than why would you have it as def in the first place and not a val?

Comment: @tkachuko Suppose that I did have `val` everywhere instead of `def`, how does that help?

Comment: it helps to get into the context you are trying to solve. You need some kind of macro tooling: did you check libraries mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850340/dynamically-creating-case-classes-with-macros ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an [annotation macro](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) that can handle this work for you. You would then invoke this macro by writing something like this:

```
@FieldsFromTraits
case class MyClass extends Foo with Bar
```

Annotation macros can then rewrite your case class with information from the traits.

A library that does something similar is [MetaRest](https://github.com/pathikrit/metarest). You might try to adapt that implementation. I'll see if I can't put something together tonight.

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I was thinking about. I think I'm gonna give adapting that implementation a go.